# Trying to create database using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to create a databases using the flask-SQLAlchemy module. When I insert this code into the command line "from sqlalchemy import db".
I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\sqlalchemy.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

Here is my code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file= 
    db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False,default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullabale=False)
    posts= db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy = True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', 
       '{self.image_file}')"

class post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
    default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), 
    nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

Could someone please help me? I've been stuck on this quite some time. I've installed flask-SQLAlchemy and updated my pip. Don't know what else to do really.

Comment: first of all import flask at the top `from flask import Flask` and why there is no value assigned in the line containing `image_file= ` thats the could be the reason of that invalid syntax error and one more thing there is a typo in the password line of User class it should be `nullable` not `nullabale`.

Answer (score 0):

You had some typos in the code and not sure regarding that `image_file=` line so removed that line for now, follow the below code it would provide u with db

edited: didnt saw that image file one line updated it can you check

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}','{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"


db.create_all()  # this create the site.db
```

Comment: Nope, still brings up the same error, the "image_file=" goes with this code db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg'). It just wouldn't let me put it all on one line.

Comment: Edited the above code copy and paste it in py file and run it directly and see if it creates database.let me know the results.

Comment: I will try this when I get home! Can you run it straight from python idle? Every video I've watched, people run it through the command line.

Comment: Better save the above code in the py file and then excute from command line like this python file.py